# Problem with Propel ORM

Tags: php, orm, propel

Im using Propel ORM in my development and I have this issue:

```
$mo = new Category();
$mo->setId(7); // This Id exists
$mo->setDescription('New description!');
$mo->save(); //it should update!
```

Well, it doesn't updates the values. It throws an exception and says that I cannot insert a duplicate key. Is there a way to go around this?

Hope someone can help,
David

[EDIT]

I know that I can do this:

```
$mo = CategoryQuery::create()
             ->findByPk(7)
             ->setDescription("something")
             ->save();
```

I know that this works, but due to my project's specific problems I cannot do that. So that's the WHY of the question.

Thanks again!

Comment: I am using Doctrine so this is just wild guess. Problem is maybe if you have put auto increment on id.

Comment: According to the Propel Docs that's the correct way to do it (the one you don't want to use). Is it possible in your project to pass the desired object into this function and have it edit and save there? Can you give us an example to why it's impossible to use the 'proper' method?

Comment: I think I'll have to look some way around the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### "Faking" an existing object

Propel chooses between an insert and an update based on the result of calling `isNew()` on the object you want to save (see your `BaseCategory::save()` function: `$isInsert = $this->isNew();`). So you can trick it into thinking it is an existing object by changing this property yourself: `$mo->setNew(false);`. `isNew()` and `setNew()` are defined in [the `BaseObject` class](http://www.propelorm.org/browser/tags/1.5.4/runtime/lib/om/BaseObject.php#L87).

In general, it may not be a good idea to work with partially-hydrated objects (which is what you seem to be doing here: you create an object, but then don't fill in all the properties with their actual database values). Some behaviors or your own code might depend on two properties of the object, and then give incorrect results. A simplified example: if you have an auto-generated field `nameAndDescription`, which you set to the concatenation of the `name` and the `description` fields on save (by extending the Propel object, via the new `preInsert()` and `preUpdate()` hooks), this will not do what you expect if you update your object like you do it here. But that's the only caveat I know, and it's probably a situation you have under control.

### Updating fields without creating an object

If you only want to update some fields, and maybe even on multiple objects (for example: for all `Order` objects with an `executionDate` before today, set the `status` to `"archived"`), you can do this by calling [`BasePeer::doUpdate()`](http://www.propelorm.org/browser/tags/1.5.4/runtime/lib/util/BasePeer.php#L329) yourself. The first argument is your select Criteria object: all `Order` objects with an `executionDate` before today. The second argument is also a Criteria object, but this is used to store the new values: `status` to `"archived"`. It should look like this (untested):

```
// This probably also works with a Query object
$selectCriteria = new Criteria(OrderPeer::DATABASE_NAME);
$selectCriteria->add(OrderPeer::EXECUTION_DATE, time(), Criteria::LESS_THAN);

// And this too, it's just used as a simple hash table
$valueCriteria = new Criteria(OrderPeer::DATABASE_NAME);
$valueCriteria->add(OrderPeer::STATUS, "archived");

$con = Propel::getConnection(OrderPeer::DATABASE_NAME, Propel::CONNECTION_WRITE);
BasePeer::doUpdate($selectCriteria, $valueCriteria, $con);
```

This method will of course not execute any `preUpdate()` or `postUpdate()` hooks you defined in PHP code, as the generated objects are completely bypassed. So only use this when it is absolutely necessary (for performance reasons?), and you know there are no other "stale" objects around.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be like the old thread anyway here is the updated answer I would like to mentions

```
$q = array(1,2,3,4);
$rp = RolesPermissionsQuery::create()->filterById($roleId)->findOneOrCreate();
$rp->setRolesId($roleId);
$rp->setPermissions(serialize($q));
$rp->save();
```

In the above code the propel will either create new row or update the existing row based on the condition. Hope this might help someone.

Comment: I'd say ->findOneOrCreate() is the best and really the only answer to this question. It's clean and quick.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to work around this will be to query the entity first, and then update it (so that you're not working with a detached entity):

```
$mo = CategoryPeer::retrieveByPK(7);
$mo->setDescription('New description!');
$mo->save(); // should work since the entity was retrieved first
```

If you need to be able to update without querying first, I'm afraid I'm too much of a Propel novice to advise on that. It's probably possible to do a manual SQL statement, but there may also be a way to attach an instance for which you've manually set the id. Perhaps another answerer can enlighten us.

Comment: I agree with you and its perhaps the better solution, but is not what I want, Ill edit the question. [edit]It should be CategoryQuery::create()->finByPk(7);

Comment: Good to know, thanks for updating the question. I'm afraid I don't have the answer you're looking for, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use Find One Or Create this will find or create a object

$mo = CategoryQuery::create()
             ->filterByPk(7)
             ->findOneOrCreate();

$mo->setDescription("something");

if ($mo->validate()) { $mo->save() }